# How do I simulate sms text in HTML5 code?

Tags: html, css, text

I am working on a series of web pages (a piece of fiction) that include text that is intended to look like it is from a SMS texting app. I want to 'simulate' that in the HTML code so that the bubbles auto size from right for some and left for others to accommodate the (up to a point before wrapping). I want the right and left messaging to actually work from the left and right margins of the #style in the CSS. Is there a way to do this?

This code comes close, but it doesn't really get close to the right margin and the background size is fixed. It can't autosize to the text.

```
.bubR {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background: green;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 10.0pt;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    position:right;
}
.bubL {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10.0pt;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    position:left;
}
```

The HTML Snippet.

```
<P><span class="capALL"><B>O</B></span>ne click. That&#8217;s all it took.  This  this is an example with the  margin: 5px auto; in the bubR style. As yuo can see the right bubble is really in the middle. The text is on the right of the bubble, but the bubble placement is wrong.</P>
<P Class="bubL"> Hi! How are you?</P>
<P Class="bubR">Good and you?</P>
<P Class="bubL">What time is it there?</P>
<P Class="bubR">Same time as you. I am in the Philippines.</P>
<P Class="bubL">Really?</P>
<P Class="bubR">Yes.</P>
```

I have have tried this both without the 'auto' and also removing the margin argument entirely. I will attempt to include them here.

IMPORTANT: **I have NOT changed the code sample** at all between the three examples!

As it was **with the magin**,
then **without the margin**, and last
with the **margin but without the auto**.

[image: As per code snippet]
[image: Without the margin entirely]
[image: With the margin but removing the 'auto']

Now, it I change the CSS code to this:

```
.reply {
    font-size:10.0pt;
    margin-left: 13%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family:"Helvetica","sans-serif"; 
    font-style: italic;
    background: green;
    color:white;
}

.sms {
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 13%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Helvetica","sans-serif"; 
    font-style: italic;
    color:white;
    background: blue;
}
```

And the HTML code looks like this:

```
<P><span class="capALL"><B>O</B></span>ne click. That&#8217;s all it took.  This  this is an example with the  margin: 5px auto; in the bubR style. As yuo can see the right bubble is really in the middle. The text is on the right of the bubble, but the bubble placement is wrong.</P>
<P Class="reply"> Hi! How are you?</P>
<P Class="sms">Good and you?</P>
<P Class="reply">What time is it there?</P>
<P Class="sms">Same time as you. I am in the Philippines.</P>
<P Class="reply">Really?</P>
<P Class="sms">Yes.</P>
```

I get this. Which would be OK except that the background doesn't autosize.

[image: sort of the old stuff]

Comment: Please some reproducible example.

Comment: Why are you giving bubR a right margin auto if you want it to be on the right? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you put a runnable snippet into your question.

Comment: I have added to the original comment to hopefully answer your question and provide more detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400183/how-to-style-chat-bubble-in-iphone-classic-style-using-css-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just quickly threw this together. Hopefully you can adapt it to suit your needs. It may be a little messy but tweaking it could perhaps give you your desired result:

HTML:

```
<P><span class="capALL"><B>O</B></span>ne click. That&#8217;s all it took.  This  this is an example with the  margin: 5px auto; in the bubR style. As yuo can see the right bubble is really in the middle. The text is on the right of the bubble, but the bubble placement is wrong.</P>

<div class="holder">
  <div class="msg msg-left">
    another Left response message
  </div>
</div>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="msg msg-right">
    another right initital message
  </div>
</div>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="msg msg-left">
    Left response message
  </div>
</div>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="msg msg-right">
    right initital message
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color:#fff;
}
.holder {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.msg {
  width:relative;
}
.msg-right{
  background-color:blue;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:20px;
  float:right;
}
.msg-left{
  background-color:grey;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:20px;
  float:left;
}
```

Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/v4b5jduc/

Comment: Wow! Wonderful **and perfect.** I did make a few tweaks, narrowing the blocks, the padding and modifying the margin. I set the height:relative. By adding things such as 
 margin-left: 35%;
 margin-right: 13%;
for the right block and
 margin-left: 13%;
 margin-right: 35%;
for the left block, I have exactly what I was hoping for. I cannot thank you enough